# c# datatable into chart

Tags: c#, datatable, data-manipulation

image shows my result from my datatable, it is calculate using linq every each of them (normal, css, sql injection, unicode, proxy attack, total hits)

code:

```
int normalcount = my_datatable
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Resource") == "1")
                  .Count();

string totalnormal = normalcount.ToString();
normTxtBox.Text = totalnormal;

int csscount = my_datatable
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Resource") == "2")
               .Count();

string csstotal = csscount.ToString();
cssTxtBox.Text = csstotal;
```

[image: datatable]

What i really want to achieve is can i get something similar to this chart base on my result  from the datatable linq

[image: datatable]

Comment: what tool are u using to show the chart ? (chart.js or anything)

Comment: That is from Microsoft word chart just for showing purpose. I dont mind how my chart will look like as long it display something similar like that. :)

Comment: You really should specify what are you trying to build. Wpf, xamarin, Mvc, WebForms... the question is not specific enough.

Comment: Im using c# visual studio. Im trying to build a webserver log pre processing framework. After it goes through few process, i change certain url links into discrete values where normal attack = 1, css attack = 2 and so on... (refer table) according to their criteria. That, i already completed. I also already perform the linq sorting to display in my textbox (refer second image). Only left the last part which is, to plot those obtain value (first image) into a simple chart.

Comment: Again what are you using WebForms, MVC?

Comment: Also you query seams to be the absolute worst way of doing this terrible unoptimized.

Comment: Just using a simple datagridview. It's okay if it's unoptimized because this is just for my own learning purpose since c# is a new language for me too. If so, do give me explanations or any improvement that i could apply in my codes. Thanks.